# When grep match fails, still print output from command

Tags: ruby, bash, rspec

This is in a Rakefile and i am doing a grep on the output of a command, when the output is a failure the grep command prints out the output from before and after the statement its looking for. However when it succeeds it does not print any output, just 'Rspec Succeeded'. I need to print the whole output even if the grep match is not successful.

```
system( "cd site-modules/profiles && rspec | grep -A 1000 -B 1000 -Ee 'Code coverage. Must be at least [0-9]+(\.?[0-9]?[0-9]?)?% of code coverage' -e 'profiles::linux' ")

if $?.success?
  abort "Rspec FAILED"
else
  print "RSpec Succeeded"
end
```

Comment: Use `%x[]` or backticks (or `Popen3`, but here it’s an overkill) to capture the shell command output.

Comment: Could you give me an example, using the code above? im quite new to ruby

Answer (score 0):

To capture shell output one might use `%x` sigil and/or backticks:

```
puts "=" * 80
puts %x("ls")
puts "=" * 80

if $?.success?
  puts "Success!"
else
  puts "Error happened. Status: #{$?}"
end
```